# Use TRUST Design Tablet with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, driver, inkscape

I have a `TRUST Slimline Design Tablet for MAC #15908` and I would like to use it with InkScape under Windows 7. Is there a way to do it?

I browsed for drivers on the TRUST website and I only found them for OSX (see [here](http://www.trust.com/it/product/15908-wireless-scroll-tablet-tb-4200#downloads)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: install the drivers for a similar product, i.e. the #15357. Link: http://www.trust.com/en/product/15357-sketch-design-tablet-mouse#downloads